# Wiremock verify headers contains many values via custom ValueMatcherStrategy

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm using wiremock to test a client. One particular test is to verify that the client send one header with a comma separated list of values. 
However those values are from an unordered collection. So it can be `first,second` or `second,first` and both are valids.

Sadly, I cannot find any `ValueMatchingStrategy` that can be used for that. `containing` expect only one value.

I tried to build a custom `ValueMatcherStratgey` but the `isMatchFor` method is never called.

```
new ValueMatchingStrategy(){
    @Override
    public ValuePattern asValuePattern() {
        return new ValuePattern(){
            @Override
            public boolean isMatchFor(String value) {
                return value.contains("first") && 
                       value.contains("second") &&
                       value.contains(",");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to verify that a header contains more than one value ? Or how can I create a custom matcher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the doc for creating custom matchers?
http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#custom-request-matchers

Comment: I was trying with an oldre WireMock version. `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.RequestMatcherExtension` work fine. You have to use if via `verify(RequestPatternBuilder.forCustomMatcher(new RequestMatcherExtension(){...}));` (that is not well documented)

Comment: Now it will be documented. https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/pull/777